# $\sum_{k=1}^n(k!)(k^2+k+1)$ for $n=1,2,3...$ and obtain an expression in terms of $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, factorial

Find a closed expression in terms of $n$.
$$\sum_{k=1}^n(k!)(k^2+k+1); n=1,2,3...$$
 Any idea about how to do this.. I'm a new to this so a little explanation would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write $k^2+k+1 = (k+1)^2-k$ so that

$$(k!)(k^2+k+1) = (k+1)(k+1)! - k \, k!$$

Now you have a telescoping sum.

Answer (score 1):

$$\sum_{k=1}^n(k!)(k^2+k+1)=\sum_{k=1}^n(k!)(k^2+2k+1-k)$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n(k!)[(k+1)^2-k]$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n(k+1)!(k+1)-k(k)!$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n(k+1)!(k+2-1)-(k+1-1)(k)!$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n[(k+2)!-(k+1)!-(k+1)!+(k)!]$$
$$=\sum_{k=1}^n[(k+2)!-(k+1)!]-\sum_{k=1}^n[(k+1)!-(k)!]$$
$$=(n+2)!-2-[(n+1)!-1]$$
$$=(n+2)!-(n+1)!-1$$

This is the req. sum.