# Find the value of n if:

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, summation, factorial

$$\sum_{k=0}^n (k^{2}+k+1) k! = (2007).2007!$$

How to approach this problem? In need of ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1494022/sum-k-1nkk2k1-for-n-1-2-3-and-obtain-an-expression-in-terms-o

Comment: This is a [telescopic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that
$$
\begin{align}
(n+1)(n+1)!-n\,n!
&=\left((n+1)^2-n\right)n!\\
&=\left(n^2+n+1\right)n!
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{2006}\left(n^2+n+1\right)n!
&=\sum_{n=0}^{2006}\left((n+1)(n+1)!-n\,n!\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^{2007}n\,n!-\sum_{n=0}^{2006}n\,n!\\[9pt]
&=2007\cdot2007!-0\cdot0!
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Could you explain what you did in last two steps?

Comment: In the second step, I reindexed the first sum substituting $n\mapsto n-1$, which increases the limits on the sum by $1$. In the third step, I cancelled all of the identical terms. This is known as a [Telescoping Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series).